# Can't find GADUnifiedNativeAdView in GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-ads-api, google-mobile-ads

In *podfile.lock* I have:

> - Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (8.7.0):
>
>   - GoogleAppMeasurement (< 9.0, >= 7.0)
>   - GoogleUserMessagingPlatform (>= 1.1)

This code works fine, so the SDK installed successfully.

```
import GoogleMobileAds

 let options = GADMultipleAdsAdLoaderOptions()
 options.numberOfAds = 5
 adLoader = GADAdLoader(adUnitID: adUnitID, rootViewController: requester, adTypes: [.native], options: [options])
 adLoader.delegate = self
```

But I can display the received GADNativeAd, because views are unaccessible.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class FeedAdTVC: UITableViewCell {

    func setup(with: GADNativeAd) {
        let templateView = GADUnifiedNativeAdView()
    }
}
```

I got: **Cannot find 'GADUnifiedNativeAdView' in scope**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `GADUnifiedNativeAdView` has been removed in version 8 of Google Ad Manager, and it seems to be replaced with `GADNativeAdView`.

Check the migration guide [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration#interstitial).